# Prevent Users From Logging Into the Physical Server's Active Directory But Allow Workstation Logon

Tags: active-directory

I'm fairly new to group policy management. I'm running Windows Server 2008 R2 with Active Directory setup. I have setup my users, assigned them to the proper groups, which consists of regular users, admins/super admins, and some Local Workstation Admins.

I'm trying to prevent users from physically walking up to the server and logging in with their credentials, just like if it were one of our workstations. I want them to be able to login to any of the workstations in the building with their credentials, but not the server. It seems if I change the GPO to deny logon locally, it also denies them the ability to logon to their workstation, as well as the server.

Is it possible to allow only Super Administrators to logon to the physical server, while still allowing Users to logon to their workstations?

Comment: You put the servers in a different OU than the workstations and apply separate GPO.

Comment: Is this server your (only) domain controller as well?

Comment: Change the local server policy to deny login locally to Domain Users.

Comment: uSlackr, I believe that's default as part of the Default Domain Controllers policy.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that the server is in a different OU than the workstations, and apply different GPOs to the server OU versus the workstation OU.

Answer (score 0):

Old question but I think it could use a more detailed treatment.

By the way the question is worded and the situation described, it sounds like the OP is modifying the `Default Domain Policy`. This policy applies to the entire domain across the board. It's best practice to limit modifications to this policy to Default Domain Security Policy Settings:

- Password Policy
- Domain Account Lockout Policy
- Domain Kerberos Policy

The best solution to the problem, then, is to create a new Group Policy Object that defines the settings you need to apply; in this case User Rights Assignment. In Group Policy Management, create a new GPO, name it appropriately, then edit it to add the User Rights Assignment settings you need.

Group Policies apply to Organizational Units in Active Directory (also to sites in AD Sites and Services, but that's not what we're talking about today). You should create a new OU in Active Directory Users and Computers. Name it appropriately and make sure it fits within the logical structure you've outlined for your organization, and then move all of the objects into this container that need the policy settings you're defining applied to it. In this case, move your member servers into this OU.

Then in Group Policy Management, link the new Group Policy Object to the new OU. Computer settings in the GPO will apply to computers within this OU.

A common practice in AD OU structure is to organize OUs into a "tree" format that allows policies to be inherited further down the tree. For example, you might create a "Computers" organizational unit, and beneath that create two more OUs named "Workstations" and "Member Servers". This allows you to create a single policy that applies to all computers at the Computers OU, while separating workstation policies from server policies. How you define your OU structure will depend largely upon the needs of your organization and the policies you define.

The specific User Rights Assignment settings that allow or deny a user access to log on to a computer are `Allow log on locally` and `Deny log on locally` respectively. Modifying these settings incorrectly can break stuff. Note that defining `Allow log on locally` overwrites the default settings, effectively denying access to any account or group not explicitly defined in this setting. Note also that `Deny log on locally` supercedes `Allow log on locally` if there's a conflict (e.g. if an account is defined in both settings, access will be denied).

Please note Microsoft's warnings on modifying the `Allow log on locally` and `Deny log on locally` Group Policy settings:

- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/allow-log-on-locally
- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/deny-log-on-locally